# ::CFBundleLoadExecutable Can not load compiled bundle (Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.6)

Tags: c++, macos, bundle, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6

uFunction **::CFBundleLoadExecutable** returns me FALSE after trying to loading compiled bundle.
When I tried to use function **::CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError** instead the error I got was:

CFBundleExecutableLoadError = -2002

The reason string is: The bundle is damage or missing necessary resources

The suggesting is: Try to reinstall the bundle.

As you can see, this is an extremely helpful information. Maybe someone can suggest a better way to understand what is the problem with the bundle? Thanks!

**Update:**
If I launch an application through XCode - everything works. (Even if it is Release compilation). But if I run application from Menu / Command Line - CFBundleExecutableLoadError fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem eventually.
There was a dependency in the bundle's DLL on one of the libraries, which name was changed during the Post-Build stage by install_name_tool.
install_name_tool location was changed in Xcode 4.6, so this step was missing, therefore bundle's dll looked for the wrong library in wrong location.

I guess giving error like "Library XXXXX in missing" is too much for Apple....

Hope it will help someone someday.